# How to increase RemoteWebDriver's HTTP request timeout

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver, safaridriver

I am using selenium "selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar" and started hub and node as shown below. Hub is running on a Windows PC and the Safari node is on a MacMini.

```
java -Xmx4000m -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -host 192.168.160.116 -role hub -port 4444 -browserTimeout 300 -timeout 300

sudo java -Xmx6000m -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.160.116:4444/grid/register -port 5555 -browser browserName=safari,version=12,platform=mac,acceptSslCerts=true,javascriptEnabled=true -host 192.168.160.72 -debug
```

This is the code for instantiating RemoteWebDriver. I tried using "             `options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.Timeouts, Settings.PageTimeout.TotalSeconds);`", But this throws an exception saying "expected an object value for timeouts, but was 180", Then I passed a time span object, but no luck either.

```
case "Safari":
                    var options = new SafariOptions();
                    options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "safari");
                    options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.PlatformName, "MAC");
                    options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "12");
                    options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);
                    options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.IsJavaScriptEnabled, true);
                    options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.Debug);
                    options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Driver, LogLevel.Debug);
                    var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(Settings.RemoteServerAddress), options);
                    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Settings.PageTimeout.TotalSeconds);
                    return driver;
```

Some of the tests fail with the below exception. Anyone come across this situation?

```
[20:55:15][Step 5/8] [ERROR] Name of my cool scenario - valid code: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://192.168.160.116:4444/wd/hub/session timed out after 60 seconds. -> The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
[20:55:15][Step 5/8]   OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://192.168.160.116:4444/wd/hub/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
[20:55:15][Step 5/8]      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
[20:55:15][Step 5/8]      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
[20:55:15][Step 5/8]      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[20:55:15][Step 5/8]      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
[20:55:15][Step 5/8]      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
[20:55:15][Step 5/8]      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
[20:55:15][Step 5/8]      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
[20:55:15][Step 5/8]      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
[20:55:15][Step 5/8]      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
[20:55:15][Step 5/8]      at Summatix.Automation.WebDriver.WebDriverFactory.DoCreate(String key)
[20:55:15][Step 5/8]      at Summatix.Automation.WebDriver.WebDriverFactory.Create(String key)
```

Comment: Hi  DebanjanB, Can you please read the question again. In my command, I have set the -timeout when starting the HUB to 300, but exception says "timed out after 60 seconds" We are talking about two different things here I believe. From my understanding, This is WebDriver HTTP client making REST calls timing out.

Comment: Figured out, new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(Settings.RemoteServerAddress), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));   @DebanjanB You have incorrectly mark this as a duplicate.